# Creating smarty function for use in template

Tags: php, templates, testing, components, smarty

Having trouble following the very simple example for creating a function to use in my template. I'm hoping in the end to just be able to use this as a means to get data for a menu.

I've butchered the example a little but this is only to get it working.
I created a function.load_ticker.php file in the plugins directory (even did a getPluginsDir() to make sure it's the right path)

```
function smarty_function_load_ticker($params, $smarty)
{
  // assign template variable
  $smarty->assign('test', '123');
}
```

So then in my shortcuts.tpl file i have

```
{load_ticker} {$test}
```

Then i get lots of the following...

Array ( [0] => /var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/plugins/ ) #0 __my_app_autoload(Smarty_Internal_Compile_Load_Ticker) #1 spl_autoload_call(Smarty_Internal_Compile_Load_Ticker) #2 class_exists(Smarty_Internal_Compile_Load_Ticker) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:770] #3 Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->getTagCompiler(load_ticker) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:747] #4 Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->callTagCompiler(load_ticker, Array (), Array ()) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:1486] #5 Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTag2(load_ticker, Array (), Array ()) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:550] #6 Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTag(load_ticker, Array ()) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:2104] #7 Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_r12() called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:2777] #8 Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_reduce(12) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:2872] #9 Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->doParse(3, ) called at [/var/www/html/my_app/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php:128] #10 Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler->doCompile(
{include file="sidebar.tpl"}
{load_ticker} {$test}

My smarty version is 4.3.0 and my php version is 7.2 (which i know is old, maybe that's the problem?)

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue may be, but to the PHP v7.2 seems to be ok, as their GitHub info claims: `Smarty can be run with PHP 7.1 to PHP 8.2.`

Answer (score 0):

Ah - sorted it. There was an autoload.php file doing some funny stuff.

Comment: Could you please explain what "funny stuff" was happening and how you fixed it in case someone else comes across this issue?